# Can anyone explain why "Anna" ++ [' '] works in Haskell but not 1 ++ [' ']?

Tags: string, list, haskell, build

I was trying to build a list of strings,  but i don't get  why String ++ [' '] works.
If i try to do with numbers, for example,  1 ++ [' '], it doesn't work .

I did :
"Anna" ++ [' '] WORKS
but  1 ++ [' ']  NOT.
What is the reason?

Comment: single quote (`'a' :: Char`) is for characters. double quotes (`"hello" :: String`) are for strings. In haskell a `String` is a list of characters `[Char]`. Hence `"Anna" ++ [' ']` is the same as `"Anna" ++ " "` (notice the double quote and the single quote). Hence `1 ++ [' ']` is the same as `1 ++ " "` which is obviously a type error

Comment: Because `"Anna"` and `1` have different types...?

Answer (score 6):

In GHCi you can use the `:info` command to get information about how a name is defined. (Aside, I have set my prompt to a lambda by adding `:set prompt "λ "` to my `.ghci` config file.)

```
λ :info String
type String :: Type
type String = [Char]
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

`String` is a type synonym for `[Char]`, a list of Unicode characters. Single quotation marks indicate a character, and of course you can make a list of them.

```
λ :type ' '
' ' :: Char

λ :type [' ']
[' '] :: [Char]
```

And double quotation marks form a `String`.

```
λ :type " "
" " :: String
```

Since the two types are equal, there are multiple ways of expressing equivalent values.

```
λ " " == [' ']
True

λ "abc" == ['a', 'b', 'c']
True

λ "abc" == 'a' : "bc"
True

λ "abc" == 'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []
True
```

And since `String` is a list, you can use list operations on it.

```
λ :info ++
(++) :: forall a. [a] -> [a] -> [a]     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixr 5 ++

λ ("abc" ++ "def") == (['a', 'b', 'c'] ++ ['d', 'e', 'f'])
True
```

Whereas, `1 ++ [' ']` doesn’t work because it requires `1` to have the type `[Char]`. Number literals are overloaded via the `Num` typeclass, so this means that the compiler looks for `instance Num [Char]`. Since that instance isn’t defined, this raises an error.

```
λ :type 1 ++ [' ']

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘1’
    • In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘1’
      In the expression: 1 ++ [' ']
```

While it is *technically* possible to define such an instance—or in fact a general instance for any `Applicative`—it’s not included in the standard library because it would be easy to use unintentionally; and if it followed the laws for `Num`, then it would behave in a potentially surprising way for `String`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the `++` operator's [definition](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.22/base-4.16.4.0/Prelude.html#v:-43--43-) says that it has two arguments, both lists:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
         ^      ^
         |      |
    first list  |
                |
            second list
```

Since `1` is not a list, `++` operator doesn't work on it.